# Differentiation of infinite series does not seem to be useful

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Trying series solution of differential equations, the routine is to define a function as a series, and differentiate it.

```
Block[{a, h},
 h[x_] := Sum[a[j] x^j, {j, 0, Infinity}];
 D[h[x], x] // InputForm
]
```

and I obtained

```
Sum[j x^(-1 + j) a[j], {j, 0, Infinity}]
```

I think this is not acceptable in any practical applications.

Actually, when there is an infinite, I can hardly do any further calculations. For example, if I try

```
Block[{a, h, c},
 h[x_] := Sum[a[j] x^j, {j, 0, Infinity}];
 Series[D[h[x], x] - c h[x], {x, 0, 4}]
] // InputForm
```

I got

```
Sum[j x^(-1 + j) a[j], {j, 0, Infinity}] - c Sum[x^j a[j], {j, 0, Infinity}]
```

Which is not a series expansion. Any idea of how to go further?

Comment: You'll probably have to build your own set of rules and definitions for the manipulation of infinite sums since *Mathematica* won't make do anything without making sure things are convergent, etc...

Comment: Since the current result is not acceptable, what would you consider acceptable? It is not clear to me what the result you seek would be exactly.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/solving-an-ode-in-power-series -- perhaps with `FindSequenceFunction` you can find the general term of the series solution.

Comment: If you're on V11.3, I recommend you take a look at `AsymptoticDSolveValue`, which is designed specifically for this purpose (though it's still in the experimental phase).

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple example. You may proceed as follows. Work with restricted series, not going to infinity.

```
hrule = h -> Function[x, Sum[a[j] x^j, {j, 0, 10}] + O[x, 0]^11]

c h[x] /. hrule

(*   c a[0] + c a[1] x + c a[2] x^2 + c a[3] x^3 + c a[4] x^4 + 
     c a[5] x^5 + c a[6] x^6 + c a[7] x^7 + c a[8] x^8 + c a[9] x^9 + 
     c a[10] x^10 + O[x]^11 *)
```

Apply it to the differential equation, let c be c==4.

```
eq = D[h[x], x] - 4 h[x] == 0 /. hrule // Simplify

(*   (-4 a[0] + 
         a[1]) + (-4 a[1] + 2 a[2]) x + (-4 a[2] + 3 a[3]) x^2 + (-4 a[3] + 
       4 a[4]) x^3 + (-4 a[4] + 5 a[5]) x^4 + (-4 a[5] + 
       6 a[6]) x^5 + (-4 a[6] + 7 a[7]) x^6 + (-4 a[7] + 
       8 a[8]) x^7 + (-4 a[8] + 9 a[9]) x^8 + (-4 a[9] + 10 a[10]) x^9 + O[x]^10 == 0   *)
```

LogicalExpand gives conditions for every power of x.

```
le = LogicalExpand[eq]

(*   -4 a[0] + a[1] == 0 && -4 a[1] + 2 a[2] == 0 && -4 a[2] + 3 a[3]  == 0 
&& -4 a[3] + 4 a[4] == 0 && -4 a[4] + 5 a[5] == 0 
&& -4 a[5] + 6 a[6] == 0 && -4 a[6] + 7 a[7] == 0 
&& -4 a[7] + 8 a[8] == 0 && -4 a[8] + 9 a[9] == 0 
&& -4 a[9] + 10 a[10] == 0   *)
```

Solve this together with the initial conditions h[0]==2 to get all a[i].

```
sol = Solve[le && (h[x] /. hrule /. x -> 0) == 2, 
       Table[a[i], {i, 0, 10}]]

(*   {{a[0] -> 2, a[1] -> 8, a[2] -> 16, a[3] -> 64/3, a[4] -> 64/3, 
       a[5] -> 256/15, a[6] -> 512/45, a[7] -> 2048/315, a[8] -> 1024/315, 
       a[9] -> 4096/2835, a[10] -> 8192/14175}}   *)
```

The approximating function is then

```
hsol[x_] = h[x] /. hrule /. First@sol // Normal

(*   2 + 8 x + 16 x^2 + (64 x^3)/3 + (64 x^4)/3 + (256 x^5)/15 + (
     512 x^6)/45 + (2048 x^7)/315 + (1024 x^8)/315 + (4096 x^9)/2835 + (
     8192 x^10)/14175   *)
```

Compare with analytical solution

```
dsol = DSolve[D[h[x], x] - 4 h[x] == 0 && h[0] == 2, h, x]

(*   {{h -> Function[{x}, 2 E^(4 x)]}}   *)

LogPlot[Evaluate[{h[x] /. First@dsol, hsol[x]}], {x, 0, 3}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]